# Android: Issue with simple UDP program

Tags: android, multithreading, udp, packet

I am trying to get a good grasp of UDP on Android, so I am writing a small test program to set up 2 sockets on the same machine, send a packet and receive it. I thought it would be straight-forward, but something is going wrong. My code is:

```
DatagramSocket server;
DatagramSocket client;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Initialize a client socket and a server socket using UDP
    try {
     server = new DatagramSocket();
     client = new DatagramSocket();
} catch (SocketException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
}

 // Server will now send some data
  String data = "This is a test";
  DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(data.getBytes(), data.length(),
       client.getInetAddress(), client.getLocalPort());
  try {
   server.send(sendPacket);
  } catch (IOException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }

  // Client has to receive and read the data
  byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
  DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
  try {
   client.receive(receivePacket);
   byte[] receivedData = receivePacket.getData();
  } catch (IOException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }

  server.disconnect();
  client.disconnect();
}
```

When I debug my code, it goes into the last try, in "`client.receive(receivePacket);`" but it never comes back from that function call. The packet seems to be never received, but I have a hard time finding why that is.

I hope someone could please help me fix this problem.

EDIT: New code using threads. Calling "recieve" before actually sending the packet. Trying to use AsyncTask.

```
public class udpexample extends Activity {

    DatagramSocket server;
    DatagramSocket client;

    String data = "This is a test";

    private static final String TAG = "UDPExampleActivity";

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Log.i(TAG, "Starting");

        // Initialize a client socket and a server socket using UDP
        try {
            server = new DatagramSocket();
            client = new DatagramSocket();
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        new ReceivePacket().execute();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Server will now send some data
        DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(data.getBytes(), data.length(),
                client.getInetAddress(), client.getLocalPort());
        try {
            Log.i(TAG, "About to send");
            server.send(sendPacket);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private class ReceivePacket extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        // Thread used to receive a packet

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // Client has to receive and read the data
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];            
            DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
            try {
                Log.i(TAG, "About to receive");
                client.receive(receivePacket);
                byte[] receivedData = receivePacket.getData();

                // Verify that the packet is identical to the one being sent
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            server.disconnect();
            client.disconnect();
        }
    } 
}
```

Still having the same issue, it stops and waits on receive and nothing happens.

Thank you very much,

Jary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are sending a packet while receiver is not yet listening.

Try first `client.receive(..)` and then `server.send(..)`. That way `client` will be listening for incoming packets. Of course, you will have to run this in two different threads.

Comment: Thank you very much. That seems like a very good catch. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work with how I implemented it with threads. I am updating the code. Thanks.

Comment: On Android you should always use AsyncTask when running long-running or blocking tasks: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: Extend AsyncTask an put your receive code inside `doInBackground(..)` method.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm sorry, I am still having issues. doInBackground and onPostExecute do not seem to execute. I'm really confused if I wrote my code correctly. Could you please have a look? Thank you so much.

Comment: Try adding `Thread.sleep(2000)` after `new ReceivePacket().execute()`

Comment: Also try adding log statements before `.send(..)` and `.receive(..)` statements to see the order in which they execute.

Comment: I added the sleep method. For some reasons, I can't check the log. When I go into DDMS and filter by the keyword "UDPExampleActivity" nothing comes up. I am not sure why (I updated the code above). Thank you.

Comment: I'm sorry for all those issues, thank you so much for helping me.

Comment: Do not worry about it, I actually found an example that uses two threads. I will base my code out of it (http://www.anddev.org/novice-tutorials-f8/udp-networking-within-the-emulator-t280.html)